# What is equivalent of BehaviorSubject (RxJS) in Reactor

Tags: project-reactor

I am proficient with RxJS and taking first steps with Reactor framework (java).

What would be the equivalent of BehaviorSubject in Reactor?

Or are there completely different patterns used within Reactor compared to RxJS? Any good reference to learn Reactor for someone who knows RxJS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned, the ReplayProcess has been deprecated. Sinks seems to be the way to go now. This I believe should behave like a BehaviorSubject with an initial value of "hello":

```
Sinks.Many<String> behaviorSubject = Sinks
            .many() // multiple values are expected to be emitted
            .replay() // replay value(s) for late subscribers
            .latestOrDefault("hello"); // only replay latest value

// --- usage ---
behaviorSubject.tryEmitNext("goodbye");
```

The official docs mention this and can be checked here:

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/3.4.15/reference/index.html#sinks

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

`BehaviorSubject` is a hot publisher in which we could access the last value emitted even before the subscription.

There are many ways we could create a hot publisher in the project reactor. The one which could be close to behavior subject is `ReplayProcessor`. Check [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/ReplayProcessor.html).

Reactor reference is [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/).

Comment: ReplayProcessor is deprecated :/